# Loading multiple modules under same parent route in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, module, router

I' am looking for a way through which I can load multiple modules under same `path` in Angular. For example, consider I have three modules `AModule`, `BModule` and `CModule` each having its own `RouterModule.forChild` call. Now I want to mount all these modules under say `site` route.

One way I have achieved this thing is by wrapping routes in `RouterModule.forChild` call under `site` route as follows:

```
RouterModule.forChild([
  {
     path: 'site',
     children: [{}] // children goes here
  }
])
```

I don't know whether this approach is correct but it is working fine. The only issue which this approach is that I have to specify `canActivate` in every module I want to mount under `site`. While this is not a problem, I was looking for a cleaner solution.

I know there is a property `loadChildren` which could be used to load modules lazily. But I want to load modules eagerly.

I' am using AngularCLI which splits code of module I specify in `loadChildren` in a separate JavaScript file which is not I want.

I' am using AngularClI v1.2.0 and Angular v4.2.5.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure but you can export AModule & BModule's component, use both components in CModule then you can use Lazy loading to load CModule

Comment: why do you define routes in `AModule`, `BModule` instead of simply defining `routes` without modules? modules don't have any value in terms of routing. they will be merged during compilation. read [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f)

Comment: Hi @MaximKoretskyi, thanks for commenting. It always feel awesome to get answer from your favorite writer :-). Let me read the article you mentioned and I' am pretty sure I will get my answers after reading that. In case of any further confusion/question I will comment here or on the article directly.

Thanks.

Comment: @ImranLatif, thanks) yeah, do read it and follow-up

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on your goal and what you are ultimately trying to achieve, but here are a few thoughts.

You can use the `loadChildren` and "lazy loading" to load on demand OR eagerly. If you select eagerly loaded routes, as soon as your main route is loaded and your first view is displayed, the other modules marked for eager loading are immediately loaded asynchronously.

I have an example of that here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing in the `APM-Final` folder.

I'm not clear on why you don't want module splitting. It can significantly improve the startup performance (time to display of the first page) of your application.

In addition to `canActivate` there is also a `canActivateChild` so you can put this on the parent and not have to repeat it for each route. The docs for that are here: https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivateChild

Comment: Thanks for commenting. So as per your answer and my understanding of routes, the default `loadingStrategy` for `loadChildren` is `PreloadAllModules` which will fetch routes defined under `loadChildren` as soon as main route is loaded as you have mentioned. Am I right?

Comment: Basically, I' am trying to learn if I can mount multiple modules under same path i.e. `site` at one single place without the code getting splitted into separate JavaScript files. Do the technique I' am using to load child routes under `site` in `RouterModule.forChild` is correct?

Comment: I don't quite understand the term "mount" in this context. If you want to use the features of lazy loading (eager or on demand), then they *must* be in separate bundles. If you don't have separate bundles, your entire application is downloaded when the user requests your application.

Comment: And preloading does not fetch "routes", it downloads bundles defined using Angular modules. The preloading is defined as part of the route configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation. I think what I' am trying to achieve isn't possible in the way I was perceiving it. I will go with another strategy where I will instead of loading modules, will `import` route configs from respective modules and assign them to `children` after merging them (since they are just plain-old arrays) under `path: 'site'`. I think this strategy will work.